# writing trigger containing multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

So I have a table trans which has two columns tx_type and ref_nbr
and I want to create a trigger such that the trigger ensures the following condition
in the trans table.
The following two conditions should be ensured:

1. if tx_type = D or W then ref_nbr should match the branch_nbr in branch table
2. if tx_type= B , P or R then ref_nbr should match mer_nbr in mer table

Comment: Which trigger do you want to create and what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are not intended for keeping consistency in database relations. Use foreign keys for that. So make a table `trans` not with one column `ref_nbr`  but use 2 columns - one for each relation (foreign key). Additionaly you can create check constraint for making sure that correct column is filled for given `tx_type`.

If you try to use triggers, you will have problems with concurrent transactions changing related tables like deleting your `ref_nbr`.

Example definitions for `mer`, `branch` and `trans` tables with some sample inserts:

```
create table branch(
  branch_nbr number generated by default on null as identity start with 3 primary key,
  branch_name varchar2(100) not null
);

create table mer (
  mer_nbr number generated by default on null as identity start with 2 primary key,
  mer_name varchar2(100) not null
);

create table trans (
  id number generated by default on null as identity primary key,
  tx_type varchar2(1) not null,
  ref_branch_nbr number,
  ref_mer_nbr number,
  constraint ck_tx_type check (tx_type in ('D', 'W', 'B', 'P', 'R')),
  constraint ck_correct_ref_for_tx_type
    check (
      (tx_type in ('D', 'W') and ref_branch_nbr is not NULL and ref_mer_nbr is NULL)
      or (tx_type in ('B', 'P', 'R') and ref_branch_nbr is NULL and ref_mer_nbr is not NULL)
      ),
  constraint fk_trans_ref_branch_nbr
    foreign key (ref_branch_nbr)
    references branch(branch_nbr),
  constraint fk_trans_ref_mer_nbr
    foreign key (ref_mer_nbr)
    references mer(mer_nbr)
);

insert into branch(branch_nbr, branch_name) values(1, 'Master');
insert into branch(branch_nbr, branch_name) values(2, 'Test');

insert into mer(mer_nbr, mer_name) values(1, 'Test to Master');

commit;

-- working:
insert into trans(tx_type, ref_mer_nbr) values('P', 1);
insert into trans(tx_type, ref_branch_nbr) values('D', 1);

-- not working - non existing parent:
insert into trans(tx_type, ref_mer_nbr) values('P', 999);
insert into trans(tx_type, ref_branch_nbr) values('D', 999);

-- not working - wrong tx_type or wrong ref column:
insert into trans(tx_type, ref_mer_nbr) values('D', 1);
insert into trans(tx_type, ref_branch_nbr) values('P', 1);
insert into trans(tx_type, ref_branch_nbr, ref_mer_nbr ) values('P', 1, 1);
-- not working - cant insert without tx_type
insert into trans(ref_mer_nbr, ref_branch_nbr) values(1, 1);
```